# Check a List of a class for a specific variable with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

To simplify the problem i have a List of a certain class:

```
class alarm{

    public bool present;
}

List<alarm> alarms;
```

Now in some code following this i want to check if any alarm in this List has **present** set to true, so instead of making a for loop i want to solve it using LINQ. Can anybody give me some pointers about this in LINQ because i cant get the hang of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use `Any` method:

```
var result = alarms.Any(a => a.present);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, the simplest would be the:

```
alarms.Any(x => x.present == true)
```

But you can use also for example:

```
alarms.Where(x => x.present == true).ToList().Count > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

it is basic question about linq, you should google it first:

```
  var query = alarms.Where(x => x.present);
```